# Laravel Broadcasting on random channel name

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-echo, broadcasting

I am trying to broadcast the event with Redis to private channel but can figure out why the channel is randomly changed while sending event.

Controller.php:

```
public function sendMessage() {
  event(new TestEvent(1, 'test', 'App.User.1'));
}
```

channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return [
        'id' => $user->id,
        'image' => null,
        'full_name' => $user->name
    ];
});
```

TestEvent.php

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel($this->channel);
}
```

Everything seems to work fine until I try to send the event. When I look at the Laravel Echo Server log it looks like it is sending the event to wrong channel each time I trigger send message event. I.e. first trigger resulted sending a broadcast to

```
presence-App.User.1
```

Second trigger sent it to:

```
App.User.1
```

I have tried to add private- prefix to the channel like this:

```
event(new TestEvent(1, 'test', 'private-App.User.1'));
```

and it sent the broadcast to correct channel, but next trigger sent it to:

```
presence-private-App.User.1
```

It is very weird and can't figure out what is wrong with that. I have even tried to debug it with Postman and using dd command in broadcastOn() method but it looks like it is not even hitting this point :/

What am I missing?

I am using docker with Laravel framework v7.11.0

Comment: The callback for authorizing Private channels should return bool:
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Comment: Good spot, I was experimenting with presence channel and forgot to change it back. Anyway the problem still exists :(

Comment: Can you show the complete event class?

Comment: It looks like it works now, after few restarts and cache clearings. I suspect it was something wrong with caching as I was changing the channel between public, private and presence within the same event class and probably something weird happened.